# How to view the 'reputation ladder'.

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

How does one access the page where the perks that come with certain reputation levels are displayed? I remember tripping upon that page - and seeing something along the lines of "only x more points until you can *_*_" - but I can no longer find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges

Comment: Also accessible by hovering over your username on the main site and clicking on the [`privileges`](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges) link there